# Black and White Slider Filter Control

Tags: algorithm, math, photoshop, after-effects

I want to create code that works like Black and White Photoshop Filter. B&W has 6 sliders RGB and CMY that allows you control result. I'm trying to figure out what is math behind it? Any ideas?
Thank you,
L

Comment: In my experience, the consensus was usually that you need to make the sliders sum up to 100, so I guess each slider represents the percentage of that colour you need to take. So if the red slider is 60 and the blue is 40, take `(0.6 * R) + (0.4*B)`

Comment: If you set R=30, G=60, B=10, you should get much the same result as if you do a straightforward mode change to greyscale if my theory above is correct.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, that makes sense, the challenge is that Photoshop has also sliders for yellow, cyan and magenta? How I add these having only RGB?

Comment: You can convert the image to CMY and add those values in too... in OpenCV it's `cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2CMY)` for example.